# If i have an existing column that i want to modify and change its values, how can i set a conditional statement using R?

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, conditional-statements

Step one: i have a table called df.

```
 Player |Date Career High|Date All Star|All Star
       A         02/07/20      11/12/20       Y
       B         05/04/20      12/12/20       Y
       C         06/02/20      10/12/19       N
       D         11/19/20      11/12/20       Y
       E         12/14/20      11/12/20       Y
       F         03/15/20      10/12/19       N
```

Step two: I would like to grab all All Star "Y" values.

```
#If "All Star" is Y
```

Step three: Assign a value to All Star column with values of Y who fulfill conditional statement.

```
#Then assign value "P" to "Date Career High" after "Date All Star"
```

Step four: How i want table to look

```
 Player |Date Career High|Date All Star|All Star
       A         02/07/20      11/12/20       Y
       B         05/04/20      12/12/20       Y
       C         06/02/20      10/12/19       N
       D         11/19/20      11/12/20       P
       E         12/14/20      11/12/20       P
       F         03/15/20      10/12/19       N
```

Comment: your condition is not clear for changing the 'Y' to 'P'.  e.g. for the first two, the 'All Star' is 'Y' and not changed

Comment: I want to change the Y's that have "Date Career High's" after "Date All Star" like D and E. The first two, A and B dates are before "Date All Star".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, first ensure that columns with dates are in `Date` format. Then, change `All_Star` column if `Date_Career_High` comes after `Date_All_Star` and `All_Star == "Y"`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Date")), as.Date, format = "%m/%d/%y") %>%
  mutate(All_Star = ifelse((Date_Career_High > Date_All_Star) & (All_Star == "Y"), "P", All_Star))
```

**Output**

```
  Player Date_Career_High Date_All_Star All_Star
1      A       2020-02-07    2020-11-12        Y
2      B       2020-05-04    2020-12-12        Y
3      C       2020-06-02    2019-10-12        N
4      D       2020-11-19    2020-11-12        P
5      E       2020-12-14    2020-11-12        P
6      F       2020-03-15    2019-10-12        N
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Player = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), Date_Career_High = c("02/07/20", 
"05/04/20", "06/02/20", "11/19/20", "12/14/20", "03/15/20"), 
    Date_All_Star = c("11/12/20", "12/12/20", "10/12/19", "11/12/20", 
    "11/12/20", "10/12/19"), All_Star = c("Y", "Y", "N", "Y", 
    "Y", "N")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Yes exactly. I appreciate you adding the Data setup code too,and the extra line of code on how to create date data types. Luckily mine was, but i could see that being a big problem if it wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

An option with `replace` and `lubridate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(starts_with('Date')), mdy) %>%
    mutate(All_Star = replace(All_Star, Date_Career_High > 
           Date_All_Star & All_Star == 'Y', 'P'))
#  Player Date_Career_High Date_All_Star All_Star
#1      A       2020-02-07    2020-11-12        Y
#2      B       2020-05-04    2020-12-12        Y
#3      C       2020-06-02    2019-10-12        N
#4      D       2020-11-19    2020-11-12        P
#5      E       2020-12-14    2020-11-12        P
#6      F       2020-03-15    2019-10-12        N
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Player = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), 
     Date_Career_High = c("02/07/20", 
"05/04/20", "06/02/20", "11/19/20", "12/14/20", "03/15/20"), 
    Date_All_Star = c("11/12/20", "12/12/20", "10/12/19", "11/12/20", 
    "11/12/20", "10/12/19"), All_Star = c("Y", "Y", "N", "Y", 
    "Y", "N")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```